# wc_add_notice not working in production server

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, webhooks

I have developed a payment gateway for WooCommerce. The thing is, when I developed it, the version of WooCommerce was 4.7.0 (It still is in my localhost) but in the production server the version is 5.1.0. I had to use a webhook like so:

```
function webhook() {
  $data = json_decode($this->df_check_payment(), true);
  $code = $data['result']['code'];
  $description = $data['result']['description'];
  if ($code != WC_Gateway_Datafast::DF_SUCCESS_CODE){
    wc_add_notice(  __("Payment failed -> Code: $code Description: $description"  , 'gateway'), 'error' );
    wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) );
  } else{
     $orderId = $data['customParameters']['SHOPPER_documentoId'];
     $order = wc_get_order( $orderId );
     $order->set_transaction_id($data['id']);
     $order->payment_complete();
     wp_safe_redirect($this->get_return_url($order));
    }
}
```

This works fine in localhost and the `wc_add_notice` is shown in the cart page but it's not working in production. I've tried with `wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' )` but it doesn't work either, the notice is not shown. My guess is it has to do with the WC version but if that's the case, what's wrong? Did the API change? I really couldn't say if it was working in production with version 4.7.0 because I developed it before someone decided to update the production's wc plugin.

EDIT: I have updated the WC version in localhost and it works fine. Production still doesn't work. I thought maybe a plugin was putting something on top of the notice so it wasn't visible. I examined the HTML looking for the text in the notice but it's not there, which means it's not being generated at all.

This is how it looks in localhost (notice shows just fine):
[image]

And this is production (no notice whatsoever):
[image]

Comment: Change your question title as the function `wc_add_notice()` works just fine in last WooCommerce version. Its code hasn't changed between versions 4.7 and 5.1. Last change is in version 3.9. So it's something else.

Comment: Did you debug this, to make sure it even reaches that point in your code, where you are trying to call wc_add_notice?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't  show the notice in the cart or checkout when redirecting but when I manually go to the checkout again it shows just fine.